# TSQL IF Operator results invalid column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

My objective, is to select the first available address. If there isn't a AddressCity, then I should select the AddressRegion, and if there is not a AddressRegion I should select  the AddressCountry.

```
 IF  AddressCity IS NOT  NULL
 SELECT AddressName + ' is from ' + AddressCity
 ELSE
 IF AddressRegion IS NOT NULL
 SELECT Address+ ' is from ' + AddressRegion   
 ElSE
 IF AddressCountry IS NOT NULL
 SELECT AddressName + ' is from ' + AddressCountry
 FROM DBO.Address
```

When I execute it, I get Invalid column name 'AddressCity'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like `case` or `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT coalesce(AddressName + ' is from ' + AddressCity,
                AddressName + ' is from ' + AddressRegion   
                AddressName + ' is from ' + AddressCountry
               )
FROM DBO.Address;
```